# Is there a way to add a list as a reference attribute to a list?

Tags: python

Python newbie here and wanted to know if there was a way to combine two lists into a dictionary in a way where value can be a specific number.  Here's an example of the 3 datasets I'm trying to combine:

```
[17, 39, 9]  [13, 37, 13]  =  0.13517353359
[17, 39, 9]  [15, 38, 10]  =  0.055003044449
[13, 39, 13]  [13, 37, 13]  =  0.0345037548204
[13, 39, 13]  [15, 38, 10]  =  0.0801704891415
[14, 39, 12]  [13, 37, 13]  =  0.0596711995129
[14, 39, 12]  [15, 38, 10]  =  0.055003044449
[15, 39, 11]  [13, 37, 13]  =  0.0848386442054
[15, 39, 11]  [15, 38, 10]  =  0.0298355997564
[16, 39, 10]  [13, 37, 13]  = 0.110006088898
[16, 39, 10]  [15, 38, 10]  =  0.0298355997564
```

I really want to be able to sort the numbers(I have a function that does this working already) and want to lookup by the first list(but need the second list as a reference).

I thought of doing something like `name = "%s-%s" % ([16, 39, 10], [15, 38, 10])` then adding name to a dict(with the number being the value) but the problem with this I couldn't search [16, 39, 10] to get the result.  I could make a dict like {[16, 39, 10]:[[15, 38, 10], 0.0298355997564]} but then my search function breaks.

I suspect I might have to do something wonky, but I was wondering if there was a better way to approach this?  Ideally I want a simple dict like `{[16, 39, 10]:0.0298355997564}` and [15, 38, 10] being some kind of attribute that I can reference when needed).

Is this possible?

edit: more details: I need it(reference, second list) there in case I need to reference it later(in this specific example, when I come across a duplicate for [16, 39, 10] I would use the second list to differinate between the results but in my full dataset there aren't many duplicates so its just to refer to in specific cases).

Comment: "but need the second list as a reference" -- What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I need it there in case I need to reference it later(in this specific example, when I come across a duplicate for [16, 39, 10] I would use the second list to differinate between the results but in my full dataset there aren't many duplicates so its just to refer to in specific cases).

Comment: I was thinking of putting the second list, into a list of list and referring to it only when needed, but couldn't figure out the logic since the dicts aren't numbered(so position 1 in dict may not relate to position 1 in list of list)

Comment: @lostsoul: Edit your question, please, so that would-be helpers don't have to trawl through all the comments. It would help if you explained more about the relationship between the first and second triplets. It appears that BOTH contain duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists can't be dictionary keys, since they are mutable. If the data is static you can convert it to a tuple and use that as a key. The values can also be a tuple of the second list and float value.

```
   data = {
        (17, 39, 9):  ([13, 37, 13], 0.13517353359),
        (17, 39, 9):  ([15, 38, 10], 0.055003044449),
        (13, 39, 13):  ([13, 37, 13], 0.0345037548204),
   }

   print "Other list:", d[(17, 39, 9)][0]
   print "Float", d[(17, 39, 9)][1]
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I try your code it gives me the result for the other list [15, 38, 10] but how can I access the first entry?  (17, 39, 9):  ([13, 37, 13], 0.13517353359).  Seems like the first entry is being overwritten by the second.

Comment: I just did a for x in data: print x and it only lists 2 entries

Comment: @LostSoul: Thats because you have DUPLICATES, which override each other.

Comment: @Lostsoul The keys also have to be unique. Any subsequent add of the same key will overwrite the previous one. That's how dictionaries work. Since you don't give a lot of detail of what you are really trying to do we have to guess a little. I failed to notice that your data had these duplicate keys.  If you want to keep these duplicates you'll have to put them into a list and keep it sorted (use insort), then binary search some key, and return all same values around it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn the list into a tuple so it becomes hashable.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> d = { l: 5 }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> t = tuple(l)
>>> d = { t: 5 }
>>> d[t]
5
```

But re-reading your question, that's only half the battle. You also want to be able to retrieve the second list as well.

```
d = { t: (second_list, result) }
```

Then, when you need the result or the second list...

```
other_list, result = d[t]
```

You may need to modify your search function to account for the tuple being retrieved from the dictionary rather than the single value.

By the way, if your datasets do not need to change (your two lists), consider making them tuples anyway.

Comment: That was cool! I didn't think of using it this way, I also didn't know about frozensets. Thanks! I am having a bit of problem with your code though, I can access the data and the second list but not the first list(in your example, the value of t).  How can I access the first list?

Comment: @LostSoul: while you were away, Josh changed his answer. frozensets are UNcool. See my answer.

Comment: @LostSoul: "How can I access the first list" ... the first list (should be tuple) is the KEY to your dict -- it's what you are supposed to know already so that you can access the data number and the second list (should be tuple).

Comment: @JohnMachin  sorry I must be sleepy, I tried to do a for x in d and got the results but I might have to rethink this because the duplicate values are being overwritten....

Answer (score 2):

> I could make a dict like {[16, 39, 10]:[[15, 38, 10],
>   0.0298355997564]}

No you couldn't. dict keys need to be hashable; lists aren't hashable. You can use a tuple instead of a list:

```
>>> x = {[16, 39, 10]:[[15, 38, 10], 0.0298355997564]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> x = {(16, 39, 10):[[15, 38, 10], 0.0298355997564]}
>>> x
{(16, 39, 10): [[15, 38, 10], 0.0298355997564]}
```

Choosing between a tuple and a frozenset: frozensets are less efficient. More importantly, frozensets don't preserve order:

```
>>> (16, 39, 10) != (10, 39, 16)
True # different
>>> frozenset((16, 39, 10)) != frozenset((10, 39, 16))
False # same!!
```

> but then my search function breaks.

Well ummm yes, you'll need to change your search function.

**Update** to allow for multifarious duplicates.

Let's make like a database where your data is stored in a table (list) which you can always access with a full table scan, but we provide two indexes (defaultdicts), one on each foreign key.

Code:

```
data = [
    ((17, 39, 9), (13, 37, 13), 0.13517353359),
    ((17, 39, 9), (15, 38, 10), 0.055003044449),
    ((13, 39, 13), (13, 37, 13), 0.0345037548204),
    ((13, 39, 13), (15, 38, 10), 0.0801704891415),
    ((14, 39, 12), (13, 37, 13), 0.0596711995129),
    ((14, 39, 12), (15, 38, 10), 0.055003044449),
    ((15, 39, 11), (13, 37, 13), 0.0848386442054),
    ((15, 39, 11), (15, 38, 10), 0.0298355997564),
    ((16, 39, 10), (13, 37, 13), 0.110006088898),
    ((16, 39, 10), (15, 38, 10), 0.0298355997564),
]

from collections import defaultdict
keydict1 = defaultdict(list)
keydict2 = defaultdict(list)
for row_index, row in enumerate(data):
    tup1, tup2, value = row
    keydict1[tup1].append(row_index)
    keydict2[tup2].append(row_index)

def search(keydict, query_tuple):
    print
    print "looking for", query_tuple
    for row_index in keydict[query_tuple]:
        print row_index, data[row_index]

search(keydict1, (17, 39, 9))
search(keydict2, (13, 37, 13))
```

Output:

```
looking for (17, 39, 9)
0 ((17, 39, 9), (13, 37, 13), 0.13517353359)
1 ((17, 39, 9), (15, 38, 10), 0.055003044449)

looking for (13, 37, 13)
0 ((17, 39, 9), (13, 37, 13), 0.13517353359)
2 ((13, 39, 13), (13, 37, 13), 0.0345037548204)
4 ((14, 39, 12), (13, 37, 13), 0.0596711995129)
6 ((15, 39, 11), (13, 37, 13), 0.0848386442054)
8 ((16, 39, 10), (13, 37, 13), 0.110006088898)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be slightly wasteful of space, but you could two different `dict`s, each referenced by your first set of numbers.

```
{(17,39,10):  0.13517353359, ...}
```

and

```
{(17,39,10):   [13, 37, 13], ... }
```

Note that you would need to use `tuple`s as keys rather than lists since the key needs to be hashable.

Aha, but I just noticed that you have duplicate keys with different numbers and lists referenced. So you can't use a plain old `dict`.... You say you already have a search function. What data structures does it work with?